# Закрыть немодальным окно с помощью JS при нажатие на крестик

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь с немодальным окном на JavaScript, нужно сделать так, чтобы окно закрывалось при нажатии на крестик который будет двигаться внутри окна

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + 'header')) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + 'header').onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>
<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV Element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>This</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добавите пж свои стоили `CSS`

Comment: #mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    color:#fff;
}

Comment: на данный момент я не вижу никакого крестика внутри вашего блока ...